# Single command to move a domain from cPanel's localdomains to remotedomains file?

Tags: shell, text-processing

I find myself needing to do this a few times daily and would love an easier way to do it.

> The domain example.com's email is handled by a third party, so the server needs to be told this by listing its domain in /etc/remotedomains.

I then remove the domain from localdomains:

> pico /etc/localdomains
>
> Search for "example.com" (being careful not to land on "subdomain.example.com")
>
> Remote "example.com" from /etc/localdomains
>
> Save and close

And place it within remotedomain:

> pico /etc/remotedomains
>
> Goto end of file and add "example.com"
>
> Save and close

A way to do this in one command would be great! :)

Comment: not one command, but I always do `vim -p /etc/localdomains /etc/remotedomains` `/domain` `dd` `gt` `p` `:xa`. it cuts out the steps of opening closing and saving each file, though I'm pretty sure it could be more optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Is `example.com` on its own line? You could use sed to get rid of it from `localdomains` (`-i` tells it to modify the file in-place, `^example.com$` tells it to find an entire line matching `example.com`, and `d` tells it to delete that line):

```
$ sed -i '/^example.com$/d' /etc/localdomains
```

And then just append it to the end of `remotedomains`

```
echo "example.com" >> /etc/remotedomains:
```

It's technically two commands, but I can't imagine that matters; you can run them on one line by separating them with `;`

Comment: Indeed, example.com is on its own line. Thanks for your suggestion :)